# Trying to remove a bar sink faucet and we have nothing to unscrew to be able to remove it

Tags: plumbing, repair, kitchens, faucet

We are trying to replace a bar faucet that was an expensive unit but 20 years old.

All the videos we watched showed a fairly simple screw to unscrew and the faucet would come right out. With this faucet, if you look at the screw and the two plates above the threaded part, nothing moves and we can't get any traction at all.

The actual faucet can twirl somewhat on the tile, but nothing actually moves below. The threaded part isn't part of any screw or nut and the threaded part isn't threaded all the way around, it has notches in the threaded area. 
It would seem like those plates might be the working part but I can't make them move either.

What tool to use because nothing is working.

Any thoughts on what we are dealing with and how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: You may try these.  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B018N80XLQ?tag=duckduckgo-ffsb-20&linkCode=osi&th=1&psc=1

Answer (score 1):

Try using a pipe wrench placed directly on that studded nut which I point to with an arrow.

[image]

Comment: Or put a screwdriver tip against the indicated spot and hit it with a hammer.

Comment: I agree that the studded nut is what is locking the faucet in place. Channel lock pliers may be a better tool for this. A basin wrench may work and is designed for faucets in tight places.

Answer (score 1):

The crenellated ring is a large nut that holds the entire unit to the countertop. You need to unthread that nut by making it turn counter-clockwise/anti-clockwise (if looking from below).

It was likely threaded on there originally by use of a special spanner tool that is now lying in a dusty bin in the garage (or garbage). An alternative to the spanner is a screwdriver and hammer to knock the ring loose. Some spray lube on it first will help; and since you said the whole unit was loose enough to turn, you will need a helper up above to hold it.

[image]